# How do I change the console line number color in PHPStorm/Webstorm?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

I looked all over the console colors and the option is not there. Where is this blue color set? It's unreadable[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to see anything on your screenshot, but if I understand correctly this is Colors & Fonts | General | Hyperlink